# Why doesn't the Java compiler concatenate string literals if they appear after a variable?

Tags: java

I have the following test code:

```
public class StringLiteralTest {
    static void testPrefix() {
        int i = 0;
        String prefixConcat = "a" + "b" + i;
    }

    static void testSuffix() {
        int i = 0;
        String suffixConcat = i + "c" + "d";
    }
}
```

The generated bytecode is:

```
Compiled from "StringLiteralTest.java"
public class StringLiteralTest {
  public StringLiteralTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  static void testPrefix();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_0
       2: new           #15                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       5: dup
       6: ldc           #17                 // String ab
       8: invokespecial #19                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      11: iload_0
      12: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      15: invokevirtual #26                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      18: astore_1
      19: return

  static void testSuffix();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_0
       2: new           #15                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       5: dup
       6: iload_0
       7: invokestatic  #35                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
      10: invokespecial #19                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      13: ldc           #41                 // String c
      15: invokevirtual #43                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      18: ldc           #46                 // String d
      20: invokevirtual #43                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      23: invokevirtual #26                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      26: astore_1
      27: return
}
```

In `testPrefix()`, the expression `"a" + "b"` is combined into the string literal `"ab"` by the Java compiler, but in `testSuffix()`, the expression `"c" + "d"` is not combined at compile-time.

Why can't the compiler combine the String literals in the second method?

The source file was compiled with the default Oracle JDK 8 javac.

Comment: compiler optimisations are arbitrary.

Comment: Compiler optimizations are not arbitrary. They have to obey the rules of the spec, and [the spec requires that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) (1) the "int plus String" concatenation has to come first; (2) the String conversion portion of the operation must be done _at runtime_.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because [the string concatenation operator (+) is syntactically left associative](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> For example, the expression:
>
> ```
> a + b + c
> ```
>
> is always regarded as meaning:
>
> ```
> (a + b) + c
> ```

Admittedly, if `b` and `c` are strings, the expression is equivalent to `a + (b + c)`. So a compiler could do what you suggest *in that specific situation*, but it is not mandated by the specification...

Comment: In languages that let you override operators (C++, C#, etc.), `i + "c" + "d"` could have a different meaning if `i`'s class had the `+` operator overloaded.

Comment: If I am understanding the [latest JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) correctly, the spec _requires_ that the left concatenation happens first, and it also requires that before/during that concatenation is a String conversion portion that must happen "at run time". So a compiler could not legally turn this particular `"c" + "d"` into `"cd"`.

Comment: @AndrewF String conversion is done at runtime - in the case of `"c" + "d"` there is no conversion and the compiler will "replace" it with `"cd"` at compile time. If the expression is `1 + "c"` then the conversion to `"1c"` will be done at runtime.

Comment: Yes, but as described the expression is specifically equivalent to `(i + "c") + "d"`.

Comment: It seems, in case of `javac`, it does optimize the concatenation starting with Java 8, update 92 (in update 60, it does not).

Answer (score 3):

```
String suffixConcat = i + "c" + "d";
```

is equivalent to

```
String suffixConcat = (i + "c") + "d";
```

You could argue that it is equivalent to this expression

```
String suffixConcat = i + ("c" + "d");
```

which will be optimized to

```
String suffixConcat = i + "cd";
```

I think, this it the reason why the byte code does not include that optimization is in [Language specification (15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a constant expression (§15.28).

In other words, `(i + "c")` has to be new string, and `(i + "c") + "d"` again has to be a new string.

However, a JIT compiler could internally apply the optimization as it does not change the observable semantics.

Comment: I believe the problem is not that "`(i + "c")` has to be new string"; rather, the conversion of `i` to a String must occur ["at run time"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1). For the compiler to convert at compile time would be against the spec -- even if it managed to satisfy the "newly created" requirement.

Comment: @AndrewF no, the same section says, “*An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate `String` object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the `StringBuffer` class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate `String` objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.*” Also, whether `"c"` and `"d"` get pre-concatenated, does not affect when the conversion of `i` to a `String` happens. Since Java 8 update 92, they get pre-concatenated…

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a great answer.

The order of addition is defined and takes place from the left.

This:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    String x= "X" + 1 + 2;
    String y= 1 + 2 + "Y";

    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

Has expected output

```
X12
3Y
```

So I'm guessing that the compiler spots that literal plus literal can be optimized to 'long literal' but doesn't recognise that reordering the operations would have the same outcome so the verbose code produced.