# Can I stop Intellij from splitting string literals when running the code formatter?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

More or less exactly what the title says. When I <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, it formats the code according to the settings for the project. One of those settings is the right margin. The problem is it will split string literals also to avoid over running the margin. So this:

```
stringBldr.append("some text that's more than 80 characters");
```

Becomes this:

```
stringBldr.append("some text that's more " +
          "than 80 characters");
```

Which *completely* defeats the purpose of using the `StringBuilder` in the first place. In Eclipse, I could tell it to ignore String literals when formatting. Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ without manually disabling the code formatter for that section (e.g. `@formatter:off`)?

Comment: "Which completely defeats the purpose of using the StringBuilder in the first place" No, a single string literal is created by the compiler.

Comment: @AndyTurner is it? I was under the impression that it would not optimize that. Is it only if there's a variable in the concatenation that it's a problem?

Comment: I was under that impression too, until Jon Skeet put me right. I'll see if I can dig out the JLS reference.

Comment: @AndyTurner haha of course it was JLS. Well excellent then. That eliminates this need altogether.

Comment: I think it is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5, in the example box: "actually a string-valued constant expression formed from two string literals". The reference I was shown was more convincing though...

Comment: Huh, well that's impressive. Thanks for enlightening me! That also explains why JetBrains left this feature out. I had a suspicion they knew more than me (they usually do) but I couldn't figure out for the life of me what that was in this case!

Comment: Well, I'm still not satisfied. Even if the string is actually joined by the compiler, the formatter is messing the code. It's not joining the string before its split. So, I ended up with lines like:
"foo" +
"" + "bar"

It would be a nice improvement to join before split.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? want to enforce a 120 char width but not at the cost of splitting strings for 5 chars that are over the limit.

Comment: Could you please post your code style settings, since I cannot reproduce this string-splitting on fresh IDEAs (2018 and 2019)? Or is the question already super-outdated and non-actual for the newer versions?

Comment: Looks like nobody was able to answer this.. And I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with

```
Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Annotation with parameters - Wrap always + align when multiline
```

also

```
Editor |Code->Style | Wrapping and Braces | Method parameters/Method call arguments'
```

'wrap if long' or 'chop down if long'.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, try to set

```
Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Method call arguments
```

to `Wrap if long`. And potentially with `New line after '('`. It would put the start of the String on the next line and unless the string is too long on it's own (+ indent), it won't be cut into two.

Here is before formatting (my hard wrap limit is at 120 characters and the lorem is 100 characters long making second line 125 characters long)

```
    StringBuilder stringBldr = new StringBuilder();
    stringBldr.append("Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...");
```

Here is with `Method call arguments` set at `Wrap if long` and `New line after '('` selected

```
    StringBuilder stringBldr = new StringBuilder();
    stringBldr.append(
        "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course try to modify the behavior of the formatter to refrain from splitting string literals, so your question is valuable in and of itself, and existing answers to it are also valuable, ***but you do not have to***, because your question includes a false premise.

You say that splitting the string literals "completely defeats the purpose of using the StringBuilder in the first place". Actually, this is not true. The Java compiler will concatenate string literals at compilation time if it can. Thus, the expression `"a" + "b"` will be replaced with `"ab"` by the compiler, which means that:

- The splitting of string literals done by the formatter has no effect on the generated code, and
- Your original purpose of using a `StringBuilder` is not defeated at all.

For another Q&A which confirms that this is so by showing generated bytecode, and points at some subtleties of how it works that might be worth keeping in mind, see [StackOverflow - Why doesn't the Java compiler concatenate string literals if they appear after a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28730607/773113)

On a different tangent, the trouble you are having with the formatter is due to your intention to treat the right margin as a hard limit. Over my several decades of editing code I have come to the conclusion that the right margin should ***not*** be a hard limit; it should be indicative, at best. This is due to several reasons:

1. Seeing lines broken just because the limit was exceeded by one character, or even by several yet still-not-too-many characters, makes me angry.
2. Automatic formatting will never make the best decision as to exactly where a line should be split. You can create an extremely complex and very highly configurable auto-formatter like the one in Intelij IDEA, and then the trouble with that is that it will take you ages to just configure it to work the way you want.
3. When source control is involved, (and it usually is,) each time more than one line of code is affected for no reason other than automatic formatting, the result is merge conflicts for no reason. This is also why I abandoned tabular code formatting (statement alignment) even though I used to like it a lot. (Do you like merge conflicts? Because that's how you get merge conflicts.)
4. It is okay to push uninteresting stuff horizontally off the screen, in order to fit more interesting stuff in it vertically.
5. Modern IDEs support word-wrapping as a "view" option, not as an "edit" action. This means that if you absolutely cannot stand the fact that some uninteresting stuff might be hidden beyond the right end of the screen, you can ask the IDE to keep that uninteresting stuff always in your face by word-wrapping it only during display, without actually inserting line breaks in the code.
6. When something breaks, it is sometimes hard to un-break it. (The "foo" + "" + "bar" example mentioned in a comment.) Is the formatter smart enough to re-format everything properly if you increase the margin? probably not.

Answer (score -1):

Disable:

```
Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Ensure right margin is not exceeded : false
```